# Print function not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have the following print function

```
$scope.printDiv = function(divName) {
  var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
  var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=600,height=600');
  popupWin.document.open()
  popupWin.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"/></head><body onload="window.print()">' + printContents + '</html>');
  popupWin.document.close();
 }
```

I am expecting a result like as per the webpage but its not aligned properly, particularly the top menu-bars appear on the entire page of the print.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the `width` of new window from `600` to at least `800` like,

```
// here I am using 1024 for proper alignment
var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=1024,height=600');
```